# AngularJs wait for response inside run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm building an app with AngularJs, right at the start of the app I need to load some data from server. These data are essential to the functionality of the app, so they need to be loaded before the user gets to the view/controller.

To load this data I'm loading from a `.run` and storing in a `.factory` so i can get it later.

The problem is, I need to load multiple small pieces of data, like user data, orders, support tickets, etc.. Because each user has some access restriction these http's are separated. This is what my .run looks like:

#### .run

```
angular.module('mainApp').run(mainRun);
function empresaRun(factoryRequest,factoryStore) {
    factoryRequest.methodGet('getData1').then(function(response){
        factoryStore.setData(response);
    })
    factoryRequest.methodGet('getData2').then(function(response){
        factoryStore.setData2(response);
    })
    [... etc ...]
}
```

#### The problem:

The first request is always made, but the others are inconsistent.. Sometimes they don't load before moving to the .controller to get the data from the facotryStore and show on screen.

Is there a way to move from the .run only after all of the requests were made?
Or, is there a better way to achieve this result? To load data before running anything else?

Comment: Are you using angular-ui-router or the classy ngRouter?

Comment: @CosminAbabei Yes, ui-router. I tried using the resolve, but since I'm using oc-lazyload to load the proper bundle (based on the user permission) the module isn't loaded when I try to load the data, so I get unknow provider error.

Comment: I don't know, how the oc-lazyload works, but I managed to get initial data with by mixing "$stateChangeStart" and "event.preventDefault();" in "run" section. It adds overhead for every state change, but did the job for me.

Comment: You could try adding a $timeout to the entire code, to ensure that it runs at start

Answer (score 0):

This is the way, how to make sure, that the data is loaded, before every state change

N!B! I don't know, how that will work with your lazy loading

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            if (userService.userIsLoaded(toParams.userId)) {

        //some logic, with the loaded user data or permissions

            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                userService.loadUserData(toParams.userId)
                       .then(DoSomethingElseWithData)
                       .then(function () {
                           //trigger state change
                           $state.go(toState.name, toParams);

                       });
            }
    });
```